# Maximum hostname length on Linux

Tags: c, linux, posix

I am gathering the hostnames of all nodes in an mpi application. I'm using gethostname and I want to ensure I have enough space to store the resulting string. I'm specifically avoiding MPI's getprocessorname as I want the machine's name and I don't want to have to parse it from that.

There appear to be two options,

```
bits/local_lim.h:#define HOST_NAME_MAX      64
bits/posix1_lim.h:#define _POSIX_HOST_NAME_MAX  255
```

What are the advantages of each? Should I include one of these headers directly or is there a posix flag I should use before some other include?

Comment: This may help: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-hostname.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stay portable you should defintitly stick to `HOST_NAME_MAX`.

From the [Linux man-page for `gethostname()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html) (quoting the POSIX spex):

> SUSv2 guarantees that "Host names are limited to 255 bytes".
>          POSIX.1-2001 guarantees that "Host names (not including the
>          terminating null byte) are limited to **HOST_NAME_MAX** bytes".  On
>          Linux, **HOST_NAME_MAX** is defined with the value 64, which has been the
>          limit since Linux 1.0 (earlier kernels imposed a limit of 8 bytes).

---

Please [read here for the current POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gethostname.html), which also mentions `HOST_NAME_MAX` as the limit. (*This is different from earlier version of POSIX where 255 was defined as limit.)*